# In Excel, issue with Concatenating formula in Chart title with a string

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am having an issue naming my excel chart title using a combination of a cell reference and text. Whether I try the CONCATENATE function or just the ampersand operator, excel doesn't like it and I cannot figure out why.

Using `='Input Data'!$B$3:$F$3 & " DollarvsDepth"`, I receive the error "There's an error in the formula you entered"

Using `=CONCATENATE('Input Data'!$B$3:$F$3, "DollarvsDepth")` I get "That function isn't valid"

I would like to be able to name the chart from the text from a merged cell B3 through F3 on the 'Input Data' sheet, as well as some static text. Is this possible?

[image]

Comment: Just a speculation, but maybe you could trick Excel by having a new cell which reference the cell having the formula.  If that doesn't work, then perhaps the issue is that Excel requires a literal value for a chart title.

Comment: That workaround does indeed give the desired result. However, I would still like to see if there is a way to do this in the chart title--the more moving parts, the easier it is for things to break :\

Comment: `'Input Data'!$B$3:$F$3` is a range of 5 cells. There is no concatenation possible to a range of 5 cells. But I suspect they are merged and the needed content is in `'Input Data'!$B$3`. So `='Input Data'!$B$3 & " DollarvsDepth"` would be correct concatenation. But it is not allowed to be a formula in diagram title. Also `CONCATENATE` function is not allowed there. So only concatenating in a sheet cell and referencing that cell then in diagram title would be possible.

Comment: Seems like you and @TimBiegeleisen are on the same page. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am posting this to follow up on the comment I left above.  The issue here seems to be that Excel does not like having a chart title referencing a cell which contains a formula.  So, one workaround might be to create a new cell which just references your current cell with a formula.  This may not be the most ideal solution, but it is one to consider.

Comment: Seems like you and Axel have the right of it.  I'll give it a day or so before marking this as the answer to see if anything else pops up.

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with a merged cell, only the top-left cell reference is valid.

```
='Input Data'!$B$3 & " DollarvsDepth"
```

Comment: Unfortunately that does not fix the issue :(

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
=CONCATENATE('Input Data'!B3, " ", 'Input Data'!C3," ",'Input Data'!D3," ",'Input Data'!E3," ",'Input Data'!F3," ","DollarvsDepth")
```

Input Sheet:

[image]

Output Sheet:

[image]

Comment: No dice on that one either :(